# Cordova plugin issue

Tags: android, backbone.js, cordova

I've installed this plugin https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-wizSpinner to make spinner on content load but appears this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: win is not defined               wizSpinner.js:68
```

The code which I call it:

```
    loadResults: function (eventName) {
         wizSpinner.create();//plugin
        wizSpinner.show();
        console.log("homepostview"+this.page);

         this.isLoading === true;

            //console.log(this.IntegratedCollection);
            _.each(this.IntegratedCollection.last(this.IntegratedCollection.length).reverse(), function(model){

                 $(this.el).append(new SingleHomePostView({
                     model: model
                   }).render().el);



            },this);

            this.isLoading === false;;


          return this;



    },
```

this function is inside a backbone view.

Comment: What are you testing your app on? Simulator? Emulator? Real device? What version Android and Cordova?

Comment: Cordova 3.4, ripple emulator @KerriShotts

Comment: Ripple is not an emulator -- it will not emulate native plugins. Use either an iOS Simulator/Android Emulator or a real device.